# How do I defeat Raspatil and get the Fair Fighter trophy?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I got Raspatil to spawn after running in circles for a while in Oerba Village AF400. During the fight I got Raspatil staggered a few times, got it's health down to just over half, and after that I... got completely smashed!

To get the trophy I must defeat Raspatil on Normal, easy doesn't count. I don't have any roles maxed out completely yet. I am assuming that would help me some, but I am guessing that I am doing something else wrong. I know I started getting a debuff that was lowering my health. I also didn't really focus on the adds at all.

I don't think fight rating matters, I just have to kill it (which seems more like outlast it based on my first encounter).

Other than (or most likely including) getting my roles maxed out, what paradigms, monster paradigm decks, items, etc will help me defeat this beast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I had a relatively easy time likely due to my party's power, it's mostly about dealing with Raspatil's attack cycle being faster than yours. Raspatil has two gotchas:

- You need to kill all the adds summoned before Raspatil casts Beseech. It will happen after a (somewhat extended) period time after every summon, so you can't stop focusing on adds until the end of the encounter.
- You need to manage wounds to prevent yourself from getting into situations where your your party's max HP has been capped in the yellow zone, providing an opportunity for Raspatil to one shot you even with a dedicated healer.

So you need to be in a situation where you can:

- Kill 3-4 medium power adds in less ~30 seconds
- Heal back up to full from being in the low yellow zone in less than ~30 seconds
- Be able to stagger a 500%, 60 resistance chain gauge within ~30 seconds

But this is what I used (again, I'm at the end game, but most was overkill):

#### Serah

- **Crystarium:** completed
- **Weapon:** Odinbolt (156/160 fragments)
- **Accessories:** Hypnocrown, 2 × Durable Magician's Mark
- **Strength:** 539
- **Magic:** 1,220
- **HP:** 6,619

#### Noel

- **Crystarium:** completed
- **Weapon:** Odinblade (156/160 fragments)
- **Accessories:** Not used
- **Strength:** 988
- **Magic:** 642
- **HP:** 8,562

#### Paradigm pack

- Lightning (*RAV*): level 13, no infusions
- Green Chocobo (*MED*): level 99, infused with Feral Speed II
- Third slot wasn't used, but I'd suggest a sentinel for *Combat Clinic (MED/MED/SEN)* if needed

#### Paradigm deck

Serah is the party leader.

- Relentless Assault (*RAV/COM/RAV*) — Default
- Relentless Assault (*RAV/COM/RAV*)
- Diversity (*RAV/COM/MED*)
- Aggression (*COM/COM/RAV*)
- Fifth and sixth slots not used, but I'd suggest *Combat Clinic (MED/MED/SEN)* or *Discretion (COM/MED/MED)* if you can't heal fast enough in *Diversity*

#### Strategy

The cycle I used was:

1. Juggle *Relentless Assault (RAV/COM/RAV)* paradigms using ATB Refresh<sup>1</sup> to stagger Raspatil
2. Use Lightning's *Army of One* feral link ability to increase the stagger chain to 750-800%<sup>2</sup>
3. Increase the stagger chain to 900% in *Relentless Assault*
4. Switch to *Aggression (COM/COM/RAV)* until adds are summoned
5. Only switch to the adds a few seconds after summoned to maximize time on Raspatil
6. Kill adds before Beseech
7. Switch to Diversity to heal myself back up to the green zone<sup>3</sup>
8. Go to step 1.

Unfortunately, Raspatil's attack cycle is a bit faster than mine: adds get summoned earlier and earlier in the stagger period and you start to get too low in health. So after the second or third stagger, I started switching to *Diversity* and targeting the adds immediately after they were summoned. This provided less time for damaging Raspatil, but kept the situation from spiraling out of control.

After the 5th or 6th stagger, Raspatil essentially lapped my cycle and caused me to almost miss a stagger entirely. This happened to be a blessing in disguise as it essentially resynced our attack cycles.

Once Raspatil was down to 25% and the chain gauge was up to 850–900%, I used Serah and Noel's ultimate attacks, *Ultima Arrow* and *Meteor Javelin*. Then I started to get a little more aggressive, staying in the *Aggression* phase of my attack cycle for longer. Raspatil died while all the adds were active, so I just finished them off and completed the encounter.

#### Notes

<sup>Note 1:</sup>To use the ATB Refresh mechanic, perform a full ATB bar of abilities, let them resolve, then immediately switch paradigms: doing so will immediately fill your ATB gauge. This has ~10 second cooldown, so the strategy is usually:

1. Fill up ATB gauge in Paradigm A
2. Queue up abilities and let them resolve
3. Immediately switch to Paradigm B
4. Queue up abilities and let them resolve
5. Fill up ATB gauge in Paradigm B
6. Queue up abilities and let them resolve
7. Immediately switch to Paradigm A
8. And so on.

<sup>Note 2:</sup> Because of the *Hypnocrown* and *Feral Speed II*, Lightning's *Army of One* was available once per stagger.

<sup>Note 3:</sup> If my party's average max HP was 75% of what it should be due to wounds, I took one turn during this period to pop a Wound Potion to allow my Green Chocobo to heal me back into the green zone.

Comment: This was a great answer. I think my biggest problem was that I was ignoring the adds too long. This answer made me bust the game back out and finish the push for the platinum trophy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Adanion Nice, congrats! Killing the adds quickly is definitely key: without the benefits of Beseech, Raspatil acts like any other moderately tough opponent.

Answer (score 2):

i think i can shet some light on this one, as i do have both the trophies.

first giant fist, for this make sure noel has 800+ attack (i had 825ish) then go to the long gui in the archelyte steps with the following setup:

noel/serah/mon
com/com/rav 1
com/rav/rav 2
sab/sab/sen 3
sen/sen/sen 4
syn/syn/sen 5<--- not used, but handy for other battles
med/med/med 6
note: this is my standard setup, also used for raspi.

start the battle with the long gui, take out it's legs, you know the drill, when it's down switch to sab and cast deprotect, but DO NOT cast poison, it might ruin the Attempt.
then get him to stagger 999%, now comes the trick; try to time a regular attack  at the final part of his stagger.
or in my cause kee up the barrage and get it by accident.
I reccomend Noels odin blades which you get from hope after giving him the chaos crystal(serendipity).

as for raspi(setup some as above):
Be sure to take woun potions with you.
Save him for the last, he's tough start out with sabs and deshell him (poison wont work), and then switch to relentless attack (2) and keep stagger him and heal when neccesary (but DO NOT let you're health get red!).
Also you'll want to prioritise the mobs raspi spawns, take you're time as rating doesn't matter, i got the trophgy with only 1 star XD.

my monsters where:
Flanitor (heal flan) lv.34
Buccaboo Ace (rav) lv.17 (shame lol)
Goblin chieftain (sen) lv. 20ish (i normally use silver choc, but this was a makeshift measure (silver coc lv.45).

good luck!